# Do observers near a black hole see far-away onlookers speeding up?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, time-dilation, observers

I recently watched the movie Interstellar, and I have a question about time dilation, as it's a huge part of the movie. I know that to an onlooker, someone going near a black would appear to slow, due to time dilation, but what would the person nearing the black hole see? Would they see the onlookers speeding up?

Comment: The short answer is yes. Yes, they would see the onlookers speeding up.

Comment: There is a whole book on this called "The Science of Interstellar" by Nobel Prize winner Kip Thorne.  Well worth a read.

Comment: It depends on the movement and direction. For example, a free falling observer would see the world slowing down or speeding up depending on the direction, in which he looks. You should be more specific in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the person near the black hole will see everything else speeding up. We can imagine two twins A and B. One of them, B, goes to the black hole, spends there a long-long time, and then comes back to A. The time loss (or gain) effects from flying back and forth are finite, but the time loss from being near the black hole can be infinitely large. When both people meet, we know the clock of the B twin is going to be retarded, so for him everything else must have moved in an accelerated manner.

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly I got that it is going to be redshifted by a factor $1+\sqrt{2r_c/r}$